# Wordpress Screets Plugin and Ajax Login

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, session

Currently I am using [Screets Wordpress Sessions Plugin](http://www.screets.com) and using a custom login form [because I don't want to use WP_users database and Wordpress's Admin for Users. I have my own reasons behind this.]

My login setup works perfectly except for the fact that Wordpress removes sessions and I for one do not want to hack at the core files for being at risk during an update. Below is my setup:

**Login Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="" id="login_form">
<div align="center">
<div >
   User Name : <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="" maxlength="20" />
</div>
<div style="margin-top:5px" >
   Password :
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" value="" maxlength="20" />
</div>
<div class="buttondiv">
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Login" style="margin-left:-10px; height:23px"  /> <span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Ajax Script**

```
<script>
$("#login_form").submit(function(event){

    //remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading
    $("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
    //check the username exists or not from ajax
    $.post("<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>%page%.php",{ username:$('#username').val(),password:$('#password').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
        {
      if(data=='yes') //if correct login detail
      {
        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()  //start fading the messagebox
        {
          //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
          $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1,
                  function()
          {
             //redirect to secure page
             document.location='/my-dashboard';
          });
        });
      }
      else
      {
        $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function() //start fading the messagebox
        {
          //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
          $(this).html('Your login detail sucks...').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
        });
          }
       });
       return false;//not to post the  form physically
});
</script>
```

**DB Link**

```
$username= mysql_escape_string(do something to username);
$pass= mysql_escape_string(do something to pass);

//now validating the username and password
$sql="SELECT username, password FROM %table% WHERE username='".$username."' AND active='1'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result); 

//if username exists
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
  //compare the password
  if(strcmp($row['password'],$pass)==0)
  {
    echo "yes";

    //now set the session from here if needed
    $array = array(
    'username' => $row['username']
    );
    $session->set_userdata( $array );
    //$_SESSION['username']=$username;
    //$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = 1;

  }
  else
    echo "no";
}
else
  echo "no"; //Invalid Login
```

Code works great except for the bit

```
$array = array(
        'username' => $row['username']
        );
        $session->set_userdata( $array );
```

This is the only way to set a session with the plugin, but I get a error "Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object." Is there another way of going about this with my current setup or a way to correctly enable the default PHP sessions?
 Thanks.

Comment: [Screets Session Plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-sessions-plugin-with-database/3405722) released **new upgrade** (v1.2). Don't forget to upgrade core files. Because refreshing session in every 5 min. issue has been fixed. It means you may lost your data in every 5 min.

Comment: Hey Dino, I am pretty sure I am on 1.2, even thought in the main file it still states 1.0, I re-downloaded and installed from CodeCanyon to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use

```
$sql="SELECT username, password FROM %table% WHERE username='".$username."' 
  AND active=1";
```

AND

```
if(is_object($session))  $session->set_userdata( $array );
```

AND

http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-sessions-plugin-with-database/3405722

Comment: figured it out, the plugin screets does not treat $session as a object, I had to redo my code to fit wordpress's way of calling ajax from the head through my functions.php keeping $session global.